# Stop GTK from dragging the window when grabbed by background

Tags: gtk

I'm using GTK on Linux. (Both GTK2 and GTK3 exhibit this behavior.)

When you grab the window on some free space or menubar, the window itself gets dragged.

I'm using the window as a giant OpenGL canvas, and this prevents the primary mouse button presses from ever reaching the window. Double-clicks and secondary button presses arrive just fine.

How do I disable or work around this behavior? I've also tried adding a GtkDrawingArea to the window, but it still gets dragged.

Comment: Are you using KDE or some other desktop environment that has this behavior by default?

Comment: @andlabs This seems to stem from oxygen-gtk theme I'm using. Adwaita enables the `window-dragging` property explicitly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. GTK overrides the function of primary mouse button unconditionally. However, simply adding an empty GtkLabel to the window worked just well for me.

**Edit:** eventually I just used a GtkDrawingArea, because I also wanted a scroll/menubar. That works just as well.

Comment: how did you do that? any instructions would be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gtk does grab unconditionally, but you have full control of what that specific "click" will do.
Returning True from any "button-xxx" method will stop further processing from Gtk. See "Return type" [here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.signals.button_press_event).